# How to access a proxy without username and password?

Tags: ruby, proxy, credentials

I want to automate a time keeping web client, using `nokogiri` and `mechanize`. I need to connect via a proxy server, however the catch is, I don't know the username and password of said proxy server. I would like to grab the cached credentials for this proxy that are stored on the computer..

For example, in `c#` you can use:

```
string proxyUri = proxy.GetProxy(requests.RequestUri).ToString();
requests.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
requests.Proxy = new WebProxy(proxyUri, false);
requests.Proxy.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
```

This will grab the credentials that are already logged and use them to access the proxy, does Ruby have anything of the sort? I know that you can use proxies in ruby, and it's fairly simple, however I am unable to get any of the information for the proxy (username password). This proxy is not allowing me to connect to the web. Is there a way I can get the cached credentials (username, password) and access the proxy? Or, if not possible is there a way around it?

Comment: There is no turnkey solution that I'm aware of. [This code](https://github.com/zl4bv/win32-cred) is the best thing I found.

Comment: I'll be adding another bounty to this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might try and retrieve them directly from the registry. The settings *ought* to be in

```
HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings
    ProxyEnable      REG_DWORD
    ProxyServer      REG_SZ
    ProxyUser        REG_SZ
    ProxyPass        REG_SZ
```

but depending on how your utility is run, it might have troubles accessing the appropriate hive.

Or, maybe... where one utility isn't enough... use [two](http://cntlm.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: This is a great answer, and I love the idea, how can I access the registry through `ruby` though?

Comment: http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/fiddle/rdoc/Win32/Registry.html

Comment: And however, there is not a `proxyserver`, `user`, or `pass` in my registry. There is however `Proxyenable REG_DWORD`, `AutoConfigProxy REG_SZ`, and `MigrateProxy REG_DWORD`. Are any of these the ones that needs to be edited?

Comment: In that case the credentials will be retrieved from the credential store of the *current user* (which might *or might not* be the one running your program). And, unfortunately, this will happen in a *secure* way - your connection must either "speak" NTLM auth, leverage Internet Explorer for connections, or have user/pass supplied from a configuration file. You won't be able to recover the credentials in cleartext. Awkward as it is, CNTLM seems to me the simplest workaround here.

Comment: I'm going to give you the bounty